# Como se pronuncia cache (de memória)?

Tags: pronúncia

É muito comum ouvir as pessoas pronunciarem como 'cachê', mas é mais comum as pessoas escreverem memória 'cache' e não 'cachê'.
Qual o correto?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Em Portugal, nunca ouvi ninguém pronunicar "cache" como "cachê", que é uma palavra completamente distinta (um tipo de pagamento, do francês *cachet*).

Das duas uma: ou é pronunciada como *cache* e *cash* inglês (/kæʃ/), ou então é aportuguesada para /'kaʃɨ/, como de resto [o Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/cache) indica. Curiosamente, o Priberam indica também que a pronúncia portuguesa de *cash* (homófona de *cache* em inglês) é /kɛʃɨ/, algo com que tenderia a concordar. Arriscaria dizer que a diferença é o facto de que *cache* parece mais uma palavra portuguesa, e daí seguimos as regras normais da língua portuguesa para pronunciar "a" em sílaba tónica e "e" em sílaba átona final.

Comment: Sim, decididamente os portugueses, e creio que brasileiros também, tendem a pronunciar o /æ/ como /ɛ/, mesmo quando falam inglês. Exceto *apple* que é pronunciado /eɪpl/.

Comment: @Jacinto Encontrei essa pronuncia /eɪpl/ também e nunca consigui adivinhar o porque. Tens alguma ideia por que não é /ɛpl/ como as outras?

Comment: @DanGetz Erro puro e simples. O /æ/ passa a /ɛ/ por hipercorreção: nós sentimos que não é o /a/ português, e como não temos o /æ/, vai para /ɛ/.  Mas o /eɪpl/ é porque por alguma razão essa pronúncia se divulgou, e nós podemos estar a ouvir um inglês dizer /æpl/ mas o nosso ouvido não regista. Eu só passei a dizer bem quando um inglês me corrigiu. Acho que nós vemos a palavra escrita e 'inventamos' o som que achamos mais provável. Quando cheguei a Norwich comecei a falar dos Norfolk /brəʊds/ até que tempos depois um nativo me explicou que não rimava com *road*.

Comment: @DanGetz E já ouvi críticos de música e de cinema falar na rádio da Kate /bʌʃ/ e, recentemente, da     /'kaɪrə/ Knightley e do Alan /ˈtʌrɪŋ/. Outro classico em Portugal é *rugby* pronunciado /ˈreɪgbi/.

Comment: A pronúncia em inglês é de qual inglês? http://www.wordreference.com/enpt/cache

Answer (score 2):

A palavra "**cachê**", acentuada dessa forma, tem outro significado. [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/cach%C3%AA)

No Brasil, a palavra "**cache**" é pronunciada como no inglês.

- Você pode verificar a **pronúncia de palavras na voz de nativos** da língua portuguesa aqui: https://forvo.com/pronounce/